# Counting the percentage of sequences in a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, count

I have to write a function that takes as an input a string and a number "n"->number of characters in a sequences and counts their frequency in a string. As long as n=1 everything works fine but when n is bigger than 1 it doesn't take every sequence.

This is my code:

```
def compute_ngram_frequency(text, n):
    bad_chars = [" ",".",","]
    new_text = ''.join(i for i in text if not i in bad_chars)

    new_text_lower_case=str.lower(new_text)

    split_strings = []
    for index in range(0, len(new_text_lower_case),n):
        split_strings.append(new_text_lower_case[index: index + n])

    dictionary = {}
    split_strings_count=split_strings
    for i in split_strings_count:
         if i not in dictionary:
            dictionary[i] = 1/len(split_strings_count)
         else:
            dictionary[i] += 1/len(split_strings_count)

    return  dictionary
```

This is the expected vs actual for the input 'banana pack', 3:

```
expected: {'ack': 0.16666666666666635, 'nan': 0.16666666666666666, 'ban': 0.16666666666666666, 'ana': `0.3333333333333333, 'pac': 0.16666666666666666}`
actual:   {'ban': 0.25, 'ana': 0.25, 'pac': 0.25, 'k': 0.25}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you count as ngram is a sequence of n alphabetical chars, so in "banana pack" the 3grams would be :

```
ban
ana
nan
ana
pac
ack
```

Am I right ?

In this case, the following should do :

```
s = "banana pack"
ngrams_freq = {}
N=0
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    if " " not in s[i:i+3]:
        if s[i:i+3] in ngrams_freq:
            ngrams_freq[s[i:i+3]]+=1
        
        else: 
            ngrams_freq[s[i:i+3]]=1
        N+=1

for k,v in ngrams_freq.items():
    ngrams_freq[k] = v/N

print(ngrams_freq)
```

You then get the expected freqs :

```
{'ban': 0.16666666666666666, 'ana': 0.3333333333333333, 'nan': 0.16666666666666666, 'pac': 0.16666666666666666, 'ack': 0.16666666666666666}
```

It's then a straightforward exercise to abstract that into the ngrams_freq() function !